# Stop all sounds but one

Tags: actionscript-3

I posted a question earlier about stopping all sounds in a swf. Now, to do that I'm using the following code.

```
var transform1:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
transform1.volume=0;
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1;
```

Which solves the problem (mutes all sounds) but now there is an issue, I want to stop all sounds but one. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep track of all `SoundChannel`s that are currently playing back. you should create a sound manager instead of calling `Sound::play` directly, and do all the tracking within the manager. then you'll just a a method to do what you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to individually stop each `SoundChannel`.

Comment: There is no stop() method on Sound, only SoundChannel.